# Creating datasets from .tiff and vectors

Tags: qgis, python, ppygis

We are group of three masters students at University of Oslo, we're writing a research article this semester.

We are proposing a global UAV (drone) localization system by Monte-Carlo Localization and semantic segmentation of flight photage, to make UAV localization independent of GPS.

To do this we train a neural network to segment a flightphoto and then compare that to a global map.

However, we need to create datasets for the training, with ground truths. We have recieved ortographic photos and vectors from the Norwegian Mapping Authority, but we are struggling with the creation of these.

In general, we have a big .TIFF image of a part of Oslo
[image: example_tiff]

We want to extract a small portion of this, with a corresponding vector image, like this:

[image: Example of a valid data sample]

Until now, we have used QGIS to open the TIFFs and vectors, then export a compressed .jpeg of both the ortophoto and the corrosponding vector image, then use python to create smaller portions from those vector sets, like the image above, but this process is slow and cumbersome, QGIS uses approx. 3 mins to just render the images and crashes regularly.

Is there a simpler way to this, perhaps with just using Python?

Our GitHub: https://github.com/in5490-run/

Comment: Link to current dataset:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v1J9xk4DoD5OaPz3GlhrtHZZRp1yWt9A?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you actually need QGIS to render the images? You can load layers into QGIS without rendering them, by simply un-checking the box in the lower-right corner of the screen that says "render"

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.